# Subscribe to button click without inline implementation

Tags: java, android, event-handling

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    btn_client_connect.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // inline implementation goes here ...
        }
}
```

I want to move inline implementation to separate function, keeping onCreate function short and readable:

```
    private void OnBtnConnectClick(View v) {
        // implementation...
    }
```

Now I need to subscribe to the button click using something like:

```
btn_client_connect.setOnClickListener(this.OnBtnConnectClick);
```

But this is not compiled. I only have this ugly solution:

```
btn_client_connect.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        OnBtnConnectClick(v);
    }
});
```

Is there better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are other ways to set `Click Listeners` like one

you simply type in xml

`android:onClick="OnBtnConnectClick"`

and other as `Keppil` suggest

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new myClickListener());

public class myClickListener implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
   btn = findview....
   btn.setOnClickListener(buttonClcikListener);
}



private View.OnClickListener buttonClcikListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // your code here 
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Methods aren't objects in Java, so you can't do this.

What you can do is create a private inner class (or a separate class, it's up to you):

```
private class MyListener implements OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        OnBtnConnectClick(v);
    }
}
```

and then do

```
this.onBtnConnectClick = new MyListener();
btn_client_connect.setOnClickListener(this.onBtnConnectClick);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating your layout in XML, then you can use the `android:onClick` attribute for `Button`. You need to define a method's name:

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

and implement this method inside your `Activity`:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  switch(v.getId()) {
    ...
  }
}
```

No need for extra code. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing this:

```
btn_client_connect.setOnClickListener(getButtonListener());
```

And then that method would look like:

```
public OnClickListener getButtonListener(){
    return new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // inline implementation goes here ...
            OnBtnConnectClick(v);
        }
}
```

Or another way of doing it:

```
btn_client_connect.setOnClickListener(new SomeButtonListener());
```

And then that class would look like:

```
public (or private) class SomeButtonListener implements OnClickListener {
     public void onClick(View v) {
            // inline implementation goes here ...
            OnBtnConnectClick(v);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define the `Method` that the button (or the view) on click perform within your XML,

read more http://smartcloudblog.blogspot.com/2011/09/android-onclicklisteners-vs.html